# Sql Azure intermittent "No such host known" issue

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am having **Sql Azure** and my website is hosted on **IIS** of one of the VMs. **Sql Azure** and all **VM** are in the same resource group.

I am getting **No such host known** issue intermittently and stack trace gives it as `Sql exception` related to connectivity. Though very rarely on pages it shows but my logs are pumped up with log. My application is working but strange issue as it is intermittently logged but many times.

```
Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Message: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.)
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderCommand..ctor(IDbCommand command, DataProviderTransaction transaction, Boolean openConnection)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.<>c__DisplayClass4.<CreateCommand>b__3()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Retryer.Execute[T](Func`1 action, Action recover)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
Message: No such host is known
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-troubleshoot-common-connection-issues#troubleshoot-transient-errors

have been working with sql azure a lot recently and have seen these intermittent connections issues a lot. we generally code to retry connection again 3 times in case of connection failure, rather than throwing exception in first try and it seems to work out fine.

Comment: I have configured retry already, got in touch with Azure support, they suggested to increase connection timeout to 45 done but no luck. Problem is my logs captured it around 1000 times in a day. Tested for firewall setting and allowing remote connection also.

Comment: added stack trace from log remote connection is enabled and also I am able to connect from management studio without any issue.